# Automatically setting custom routes with the internal VPN (IPSec/L2TP) client

Tags: network, vpn

I have a IPSec/L2TP (PSK) VPN I'm connecting to with OSX's built in client through the System Preferences > Network (in Lion/10.7.2).  The VPN gives me an IP of 10.0.1/24, but I need to access servers within the whole 10/8 and 172.16/16 range.  By default the VPN will only route over 10.0.1/24, and if I want to access the other networks I need to select the "Send all traffic over VPN connection" checkbox.  Is there an easy/sane way to specify the exact network ranges to route via the VPN so I don't have to send all my other traffic over it, and end up with problems like their firewall blocking google?

I imagine I could probably attack this with some command line `route` directives, but that seems really clunky.  I also heard someone in passing suggest I try [Tunnelblick](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/), but I'm not explicitly connecting to an OpenVPN server, and the configuration file for Tunnelblick looked extremely OpenVPN specific.

Update: This question is covered with answers at https://superuser.com/questions/4904/how-to-selectively-route-network-traffic-through-vpn-on-mac-os-x-leopard

Comment: But do those answers work on Lion?

Comment: I have the solution working in 10.7.4.